# Analytics add-on Function to display first day of current Quarter?

Tags: function, date, google-analytics, google-sheets

I'm really having trouble trying to use the google analytics add-on in google sheets to report Quarterly data. Basically, I'm trying to set a timeframe where the "start date": the first day of the current quarter and the "end date": the last day of the current quarter. I was able to do a monthly report based off this function in "start date" =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1) to show current monthly data. But does anyone know how to achieve the quarterly equivalent where Jan-March =Q1, April-June = Q2, July-Sep, and Oct-Dec =Q4. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let's put your parameter date in A1. Then for the first day of the quarter for that date:

```
=date(year(A1), int((month(A1)-1)/3)*3+1, 1)
```

And for the last day of the quarter:

```
=date(year(A1), int((month(A1)-1)/3)*3+4, 1)-1
```